# Unmet dependencies for libcurl4-openssl-dev

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

#### I need to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` on ubuntu 14.04

I had tried both **`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`** and **`sudo apt-get install -f libcurl4-openssl-dev`**, but return:

> `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

then I try **`sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev`**, which return:

> `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    librtmp-dev : Depends:  libgnutls-dev  but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

then .. **`sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev`**, which return:

> `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgcrypt11-dev (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libtasn1-6-dev but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libp11-kit-dev (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

The dependence is endless...

Comment: So fix your dependencies? E.g., look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages).

Comment: no, I don't think that question can do any help.

Comment: I prefer `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` instead of `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. It should offer the same functionalities.

Comment: @nicola I tried `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` ether. But raise the same error.
>`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls-dev but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact same problem while installing RCurl inside R on Ubuntu 14.04.
The problem is that libcurl4-openssl-dev depends on librtmp-dev which depends on libgnutls-dev which depends on libgcrypt11-dev (>=1.4.0).

Ubuntu 14.04 (at least my distribution) has libgcrypt20-dev, and it won't allow version 20 and version 11 in the same environment. However, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

But it will replace libgcrypt20-dev with version 11.

Answer (score -1):

When i try
`sudo apt-get build-dep libcurl4-openssl-dev`
i get the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 comerr-dev : Depends: libcom-err2 (= 1.46.2-2) but 1.46.6-1~bpo11+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

similarly, when i try to install libcurl4-gnutls-dev i get the below error!

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.74.0-1.3+deb11u10) but 7.88.1-10+deb12u3~bpo11+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please add additional information in writing about how this provides an answer to OP's question

Comment: I have added more information